# timestamp conversion and fetch data within range

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, timestamp

```
     timestamp
---------------------
     14678900
     14678990
```

- I have creation of bill in the form of timestamp.
- I want to create sales report on daily, monthly and yearly basis

  - `"select id from invoice where WEEK(timestamp)=WEEK(NOW())";`
- I was fetching data this way when the datatype of field in database is DATETIME..
- I need weekly data like this but the field in database is int(storing timestamp)..
  how to do this in CI
- I know "date helper " in CI, but I don't know how to implement it, or should I convert the date in MySql query itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `WEEK()` on unix timestamp, SQL is not familiar with it.

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME` to convert string to `DATETIME`, using session timezone.

```
SELECT id 
FROM invoice 
WHERE WEEK( FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) ) = WEEK( NOW() );
```